# How to use a powershell command to check if a variable directory exists?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert a MSDOS script to use Powershell. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to see if a variable path exists.

"if exist %~dp0%MyNewPig%\PigBreeds\%Type%*%Breed%*%Markings%_%EarNotch%\nul goto skipthis"

Can you help?

The Underdog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
$ScriptRoot = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

if (Test-Path "$ScriptRoot\$PigBreed\Breeds\$MyNewPig_$PitBreed_$EarNotch\nul") {
    #Do whatever SKIPTHIS does here
}
```

Comment: That totally worked with SKIPTHIS being changed to Write-Host "This customer directory already exists!"
break;    THANK YOU BENH!